# Change value input based on selection of 2 different drop down menus options

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I need to achieve the following:

I have 2 drop down menus in a form for a phone repair shop website.
One drop down menu is called "Phone model" and the other "failure type".

I need to come up with a price after I combine those 2 selects. 
It not necessarily has to be based on the actual value of the selects:
it basically like this:

```
if 
Phone model = "iPhone 6",
failure type = "cracked screen"
print the value 200 somewhere.

OR 

Phone model = "iPhone 4"
failure type = "cracked screen"
print the value 50 somewhere.
```

Example of what I need to do:

[image]

How could I do that?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: how can I do this!

Comment: You asked if it was possible!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, try yourself first, if get stuck then come here and add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See my answer below, Hope that will cover your question. And don't forget to vote up and approve answer if it fix your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

get 1st and 2nd drop down value, and then put a check on both of these values like :

```
if(val != '' && val2 != ''){
    if(val1 = 'text1' && val2 == 'text2'){
        document.getElementById('amount') = '50';   // will put the amount to textbox
    }
}
```

Comment: HI! I will give it a try right now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: So I did this, but it didn't work, I wonder if I have to specifty which form I'm talking about somewhere or maybe I didn't understand the script?

<script type="text/javascript">
if(problem != '' && smartphonemodel != ''){
if(problem = 'No carga' && smartphonemodel == 'Core'){
document.getElementById('price') = '50'; 
    }
}
   </script>

Comment: the live page is www.phone-fix.com.ar

Comment: so what do you think? is it to messy?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

> Example is in jquery, but you can do the same by raw javascript.

HTML,

```
<label>Model</label>
<select id="select-model" data-toggle="price-update">
  <option value="iphone4">Apple iPhone 4</option>
  <option value="iphone5">Apple iPhone 5</option>
</select>

<label>Failure Type</label>
<select id="select-issue" data-toggle="price-update">
  <option value="cracked-screen">Cracked Screen</option>
  <option value="bricked-os">Bricked OS</option>
</select>

<label>Price</label>
<input id="price" vlaue="" />
```

JS,

```
$('[data-toggle=price-update]').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    var model = $('select#select-model option:selected').val(),
        issue = $('select#select-issue option:selected').val(),
        input = $('#price');

    switch(model) {
      case 'iphone4':
          if(issue == 'cracked-screen'){
            input.val('$ 10.00');
          }
          if(issue == 'bricked-os'){
            input.val('$ 20.00');
          }
          break;
      case 'iphone5':
          if(issue == 'cracked-screen'){
            input.val('$ 30.00');
          }
          if(issue == 'bricked-os'){
            input.val('$ 40.00');
          }
          break;
    }
  });
});
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ey7tt3yp/

---

And its more cleaner if you do like this, So you can have many combinations like these.

JS,

```
var data = {
    "iphone4": {
        "cracked-screen": "10.00",
        "bricked-os": "20.00"
    },
    "iphone5": {
        "cracked-screen": "30.00",
        "bricked-os": "40.00"
    }
}

$('[data-toggle=price-update]').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    var model = $('select#select-model option:selected').val(),
        issue = $('select#select-issue option:selected').val(),
        input = $('#price');

    input.val('$ ' + data[model][issue]);
  });
});
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ey7tt3yp/3/

Hope this helps! :)